# Regex expression retuns unexpected result on special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check whether a string contains special characters.
I am using the following `regex` for this

Trying it online with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/S4j6M2/1) it works perfectly.
However, when I include this in my code, it does not work. It always returns false... Why is that?

The `input` field handling the user input.

```
<input
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type='text'
    autoComplete='off'
    value={this.state.text}
    onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
/>
```

The `handleOnChange` handling whenever something is typed.

```
handleOnChange = event => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        text
    });

    this.checkForSpecialCharacter(text)
}


checkForSpecialCharacter = text => {
    const specialCharacters = new RegExp('/[ !@#$%^&*()_+=`~:;",.\-\[\]\{\}\'\\\|\<\>\/\?]/');
    console.log(specialCharacters.test(text)) // <- logs false
    this.setState({
        foo: {
            ...this.state.foo,
            specialCharacter: specialCharacters.test(text),
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `''` to create the regex, you should not add the `/` at the start and end and you should escape the backslashes:

```
new RegExp('[ !@#$%^&*()_+=`~:;",.\\-\\[\\]\\{\\}\\'\\\\\\|\\<\\>\\/\\?]');
```

That's a lot of backslashes, so you should just write it with `//` as the delimiters:

```
const specialCharacters = /[ !@#$%^&*()_+=`~:;",.\-\[\]\{\}\'\\\|\<\>\/\?]/;
```